# Same method name in different S4 classes in R

Tags: r

I have two files each containing a S4 class and a Generic Method . The name of the generic method `foo()` is same, but the definition can be same or different and it may take same arguments or different. Then I create a R package out of it and use that R package .

File 1

---

```
setOldClass("jobj")

Filter <- setClass("Filter",representation(jobj="jobj"))

setMethod("initialize", "Filter", function(.Object, col){
           .Object@jobj <-callJStatic(col)  
           .Object
})


setGeneric(name="foo",
       def=function(object,df)
       {
         standardGeneric("foo")
       }
)

setMethod(f="foo",
          signature="Filter",
          definition=function(object,df)
          {
              print("Filter foo")
              return(callJMethod(object@jobj,"foo",df@sdf)
          }
)
```

File 2

---

```
Jilter <- setClass("Jilter",representation(jobj="jobj"))

setMethod("initialize", "Jilter", function(.Object, colexp){
           .Object@jobj <- callJStatic(colexp)
           .Object
})


setGeneric(name="foo",
def=function(object,df)
       {
         standardGeneric("foo")
       }
)

setMethod(f="foo",
          signature="Jilter",
          definition=function(object,df)
          {
              print("Jilter foo")
              return(callJMethod(object@jobj,"foo",df@sdf)))
          }
)
```

test1

---

```
library(FILTER)
fltrobj <- new("Filter","col")
result <- FILTER:::foo(fltrobj,df)
```

test 2

---

```
library(FILTER)
jltrobj <- new("Jilter","colexp")
result<-FILTER:::foo(jltrobj,df)
```

The call to foo works in one test and doesn't work in other. The error returned is:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>     unable to find an inherited method for function ‘foo’ for signature ‘"Jilter"’

If I make it `foo1` and `foo2` it works. Is there a way to make it work or is it not possible with R S4 classes.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have a solution now?

Comment: Added a superclass which has foo method and can be used by child classes.

Comment: @MohammadYaseen can you please post your solution as an answer. I have the same issue.